# MDX Date hierarchy to date format in Excel

Tags: excel, date, mdx

I'm using a Excel pivot table to analyze a SSAS multidimensional cube. I have a date hierarchy with

year --> month --> date

that looks like that:

[image]

In order to use the excel time slicer, the column has to be in a date format.
Does anyone have an idea how to change the date column to a date format within Excel?

I have the feeling it has to be within Excel.

Comment: Use texttocolumns with a YMD column attribute and then set a cell format of yyyymmdd.

Comment: It seems you have a wrong dimension structure. Set NameColumn to the column with the correct name format, because it returns the key value which is mostly used for ordering.

Answer (score 3):

This old [white paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9982) documents how to properly mark a Date dimension so that Excel treats it as such. You will need to make a few small changes to your cube and redeploy it. See Figure 29-31 which show how to mark Type=Time on the dimension and set the ValueColumn on the key of the dimension.

> To designate a time dimension, set the Type property of the dimension
>   to Time, as illustrated in Figure 29.
>   [image]
>
> Figure 29. Setting the dimension Type property to Time
>
> Exposing Date-Specific Filtering Options If a dimension, in addition
>   to having the Type property set to Time, also has a date property,
>   Office Excel 2007 PivotTables expose date-specific filtering options
>   for this dimension’s hierarchies instead of label filtering options.
>   In Analysis Services, you do this by having a date data type column in
>   the data source view tables for the time dimension and then setting
>   the ValueColumn property to point to that column, as illustrated in
>   Figure 30. To enable date filtering in the PivotTable, first set the
>   Type of the dimension to Time.
>   [image]
>
> Figure 30. Setting the dimension type
>   to Time to expose date filtering options
>
> Next, set the ValueColumn property of the key attribute hierarchy in
>   the time dimension to point to a date data type column in the source
>   database. The DataType property should be set to Date, as illustrated
>   in Figure 31.
>   [image]
>
> Figure 31. Setting the ValueColumn of the key
>   attribute hierarchy to a date type column

Answer (score 0):

You could run TextToColumn while specifying a DMY format a achieve true dates then set the desired date format. This should be performed on the pre-pivot data.

```
Sub numberformats()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("Z:Z")
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYDMFormat), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            .NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: making the amendments within the cube is a much more sensible idea - although if not possible then above helps

Comment: @GregGalloway - Actually, incorrect answers are not discouraged on SO but it is recommended that other users (who recognize the inconsistencies) down-vote them. Providing an intelligent comment detailing the inconsistencies is optional as you well know.